# How to upgrade from 5.6.6 LTS to 6.5?

Tags: sonarqube

Can we upgrade SonarQube from 5.6.6 to 6.5 directly, or is there any intermediate step required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SonarQube will do any intermediate steps **for you**. If you start a 6.5 server on a 5.6.6 database, it will automatically detect this discrepancy and internally **do one upgrade after another**.

Side note: SonarQube in some cases even undoes some migration steps after having done them. Just to be sure that you are able to migrate from any version to any higher version!

Comment: Thanks, and what about plugins, should I expect any major changes or issues ?

Comment: @Rarar Check the compatibility of your plugins. They might not work with 6.5

Comment: Thanks, I also find this doc with Plugin Version Matrix: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Plugin+Version+Matrix

Answer (score 2):

v5.6.6 is the latest LTS, so you can upgrade directly to 6.5. See [SonarQube Upgrade Guide](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading).